# How to use AdoAppender in log4net without config

Tags: c#, logging

I have a doubt in log4net. How to use the ADOAppender class in C#. I have to capture the log in DB. I have tried by configuring in Config file.And is working fine. I need to configure it in code.

I have tried by using the following code.And is not working

```
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

        MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();
        AdoNetAppender adoappender = new AdoNetAppender();
        AdoNetAppenderParameter adoapppar = new AdoNetAppenderParameter();
        AdoNetAppenderParameter adoapppar1 = new AdoNetAppenderParameter();
        AdoNetAppenderParameter adoapppar2 = new AdoNetAppenderParameter();
        AdoNetAppenderParameter adoapppar3 = new AdoNetAppenderParameter();
        AdoNetAppenderParameter adoapppar4 = new AdoNetAppenderParameter();
        AdoNetAppenderParameter adoapppar5 = new AdoNetAppenderParameter();

        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();

        adoappender.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xmltest;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=dbadmin;";
        adoappender.ConnectionType = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
        adoappender.ReconnectOnError = true;

        adoappender.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adoappender.CommandText = "DBO.splog4nettest";
        adoappender.BufferSize = 1;

        adoapppar.ParameterName = "@log_date";
        adoapppar.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
        adoapppar.Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(patternLayout);
        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}";
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();
        adoappender.AddParameter(adoapppar);

        adoapppar1.ParameterName = "@thread";
        adoapppar1.DbType = DbType.String;
        adoapppar1.Size = 255;
        adoapppar1.Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(patternLayout);
        //adoapppar.Layout = (IRawLayout)patternLayout;
        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%thread";
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();
        adoappender.AddParameter(adoapppar1);

        adoapppar2.ParameterName = "@log_level";
        adoapppar2.DbType = DbType.String;
        adoapppar2.Size = 50;
        adoapppar2.Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(patternLayout);
        //adoapppar.Layout = (IRawLayout)patternLayout;
        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%level";
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        memory.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Info;
        hierarchy.Configured = false;

        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: I cannot update the log in table

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you tried to debug it? Adding this line to your app setting in your config file for the appender will let you debug log4net. `add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"></add>`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added AdoAppender to Root

```
hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(adoappender);
```